# How to iterate each row of an attached CSV file in Survey123

Tags: javascript, loops, csv

I have a csv table with first row being the header and each of the rest row being one record of point. The table has column "latitude", "longitude", "Station". The csv file, "1mKP.csv" is saved in media folder under my survey123 form1 directory.

Is there a way to iterate each record in the csv file so that i can run another JS script function to find the nearest record of the csv table when compared with the captured geopoint?

I am new in JS script and currently learning programming. I appreciate the help and teaching.
thanks
Xiaojian

i saved the csv file, "1mKP.csv" in media folder under my survey123 form1 directory. and i can use pulldata to look up this table. It seems to me that the csv content is attached in the survey form.

I dont know how to iterate each row of the table